# Installing Android 6.0 x86 on Hyper-V crashes after asking about GRUB

Tags: android, android-x86

I'm trying to install Android 6.0 x86 as the guest OS on Hyper-V.  I was able to successfully install Android 4.4 but not 6.0

When I run through the installation process it formats the partition then asks if I want to install GRUB.  If I choose Yes the installer crashes to a command prompt.  If I choose skip, it asks if I wish to install the /system directory as read-write.  Selecting yes there also crashes.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the main developer of android-x86 left the project, so I doubt you'll ever get a fix for this. use an emulator tool like genymotion to have andoid on your PC

Comment: Darn sorry to hear that.  Thanks for the advice.